# How do you manage and organize your game components?

Tags: .net, xna

in my spare time I'm engaged with writing a little game using Microsofts XNA framework. Reviewing the very first prototype which I wrote to get aquainted with XNA, I found it annoying that there is no possibility to structure my (drawable) game components in a hierarchical manner. I was close to implement a kind of `Composite`*(Drawable)*`GameComponent` in order to do that. But before reinventing the wheel I ask you: What is your preferred way to manage and structure hierarchically related game components?

Thx, Prensen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XNA is a framework for writing game engines, not a game engine :) You're talking about a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph)

Comment: I'll have to second this motion :-)